# How to scroll in mobile browser using Appium and selenium?

Tags: selenium, appium, mobile-browser

How to scroll in mobile browser using Appium and selenium? Scroll is working in app but not in browser. Using scrollToExact method. web app was developed using ionic framework

Comment: Can you post what you have tried please?

Answer (score 1):

There several ways how to get it done.

If you are using instance of **AppiumDriver**, you need to switch to native view before you can use `TouchAction`

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
// Get your screen size to set properly start point (startX, startY)
// and end point (endX, endY) for scrolling
Dimension screenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
new TouchAction(driver)
  .press(<startX>, <startY>)
  .waitAction(500)
  .press(<endX>, <endY>)
  .release()
  .perform();
```

If you are using instance of **RemoteWebDriver**, then you can do it like this:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.de");
ExecuteMethod method = new RemoteExecuteMethod(driver);
RemoteTouchScreen screen = new RemoteTouchScreen(method);
screen.up(10, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dmle I discovered you need to switch to native view before you can use TouchAction. Anyway that code didn't work as press method doesn't accept two int values.

Here I share the code that worked in my case, and also how to use a web context element as a reference by saving its values before changing to native context. I do also restore the previous context:

```
//Get web context element references to touch on its area
MobileElement tmpElement = driver.findElement(by);
int x=tmpElement.getLocation().x; 
int y=tmpElement.getLocation().y;
Dimension elemSize = tmpElement.getSize();
int height=elemSize.height;

//Save precious context
String previousContext=driver.getContext();
//Set native context
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");   
//Perform scroll
new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(ElementOption.point(x+5, y+height-5))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofSeconds(1)))
    .moveTo(ElementOption.point(x+5, y+5))
    .release()
    .perform();
//Restore context
driver.context(previousContext);
```